# Comparing values efficiently

Tags: java

Is there a better and more efficient way to do this:

I am inputting 2 values then checking them of on a list, as if current = three then it returns true for checking for one, two and three

NOTE: these values (one, two, three) are just placeholders for the example in my use there is no relation between them except that they have a different priority.

```
enum Foo {
    ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3)

    private final int priority;

    public Foo(int priority) {this.priority = priority;}

    public int getPriority() {return priority;}
}

public boolean checker(Foo current, Foo check) {
    if (check == ONE) {
        if (current == ONE || current == TWO
                || current == THREE) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (check == TWO) {
        if (current == TWO || current == THREE) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    if (check == THREE) {
        if (current == THREE) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Definitely the most efficient way is to use `int` values, and then compare `if( current > check )`

Comment: Use a switch statement with cases that fall through into others. I actually wrote an answer but the question was marked duplicate before I could submit... Oh Well...

Answer (score 1):

I would implement the enum this way:

```
enum Foo {
ONE(1), TWO(2), THREE(3);

private final int priority;

private Foo(int priority) {
    this.priority = priority;
}

public int getPriority() {
    return priority;
}

public boolean check(Foo check) {
    return this.getPriority() >= check.getPriority();

}
```

}

And just call:

```
Foo current = Foo.THREE;
System.out.println(current.check(Foo.TWO));
```

This way it is more OOP.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are always checking if `current` is equal to or greater than `check`. If so, then you can just use ints. If you need to name them, you can use some constant ints, such as `public final static int ONE = 1;`.

```
public boolean checker(int current, int check) {
    return current >= check;
}
```

If you want to restrict to specific numbers, such as 1, 2, 3 in your example, just check the parameters first:

```
public boolean checker(int current, int check) {
    int MIN = 1;
    int MAX = 3;
    if(current < MIN || current > MAX || check < MIN || check > MAX) {
        return false;
    }
    return current >= check;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

demostene's answer is the way to go if your actual use case allows it.

That being said, the following is efficient, clear, and logically equivalent to the code you posted:

```
public boolean checker(Foo current, Foo check) {
    switch (check) {
        case THREE:
            if (current == TWO)
              return false;
        case TWO:
            if (current == ONE)
                return false;
        default:
            return true;
    }
}
```